# Datastax rename table

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed 9 node cluster on google cloud.

Created a table and loaded the data. Now want to change the table name.

Is there any way I can change the table name in Cassandra?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename table in Cassandra CQL3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112384/how-to-rename-table-in-cassandra-cql3)

Answer (score 6):

**You can't rename table name.**
You have to drop the table and create again

> You can use ALTER TABLE to manipulate the table metadata. Do this to change the datatype of a columns, add new columns, drop existing columns, and change table properties. The command returns no results.
>
> Start the command with the keywords ALTER TABLE, followed by the table name, followed by the instruction: ALTER. ADD, DROP, RENAME, or WITH. See the following sections for the information each instruction require

If you need the data you can backup and restore data using copy command in cqlsh.

To Backup data :

```
COPY old_table_name TO 'data.csv'
```

To Restore data :

```
COPY new_table_name FROM 'data.csv'
```